# How i can acces to another class, while i'm enter the information for the first class from shell?

Tags: django-models, python-3.7

I'm trying to fill write the models from shell and i was trying to fill the information for input has ( ForeignKey ) that make it access to another class.
that is my code in pycharm :

```
class Team(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
   details = models.TextField()
   def __str__(self):  
       return self.name




class Player(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    position_in_field = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=(('1', 'حارس'), ('2', 'دفاع'), ('3', 'وسط'), ('4', 'هجوم')))
    is_captain = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.name, self.team)
```

and this is the result:

```
python manage.py shell
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from teams.models import Player
>>> from teams.models import Team
>>> Player.objects.create(name='محمد إبراهيم', number='25', age='27', position_in_field='هجوم', is_captain=False, team='فريق الزمالك')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\cj\projects\django\teammanager_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\cj\projects\django\teammanager_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "D:\cj\projects\django\teammanager_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 555, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "D:\cj\projects\django\teammanager_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 216, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'فريق الزمالك'": "Player.team" must be a "Team" instance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a record with a foreign key, you have to indicate the record in the referenced model through its primary key.

In the case of model **Team**, you didn't set a primary key explicitly, so **Django**sets de default field **mode_id**, that is a autoincremental `PositiveIntegerField`, that is what you have to indicate in the referencing record.

```
Player.objects.create(name='محمد إبراهيم', number='25', age='27', position_in_field='هجوم', is_captain=False, team_id=1)
```

If you have a model object with the referenced team, you can use it too:

```
Player.objects.create(name='محمد إبراهيم', number='25', age='27', position_in_field='هجوم', is_captain=False, team=team_instance)
```